# How to populate spinner from online XML link data

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

Want to populate the spinner from the online XML data which i am getting from link for example-http://example.com/abc.svc/APIGetalllocationAgentID=1234&KeyCode=123456789012345677544

**From the above link assume I am getting the below pattern of XML**

```
   <a:Cityvalues>
    <a:FromCityId>123</a:FromCityId>
    <a:FromCityCameIdName>Cityname</a:FromCityCameIdName>
    <a:ToCityId>321</a:ToCityId>
    <a:ToCityNameidName>Cityname</a:ToCityNameidName>
    </a:CityValues>
```

**From the above XML value format which i am getting from the link..want to fill the spinner of android of tag** `<a:FromCityCameIdName>Cityname</a:FromCityCameIdName>` **i.e the spinner should display Cityname**

Answer (score 0):

Before set it in spinner you require to parse it. Following is the url which help you how to parse xml data ?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: hi thanks!! could you provide any link where spinner is being populated not the text of edit text field.

Comment: Hi, i dont understand your query can explain in detail what actually you want .

Comment: Like above is the pattern of the xml which i am getting from the link and then directly i want to populate all the values of the <a:FromCityName>Gurgaon</a:FromCityName>.. <a:FromCityName> xml tag's value i.e Delhi,gurgaon,Bangalore etc etc value to the spinner

Comment: @ Dhavalkumar Solanki Please help